# How to run Robot Framework/Sikuli test cases with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, robotframework, sikuli

I am trying to run some automated tests for desktop apps. The code is written in Robot Framework and Sikuli. If I run them from command line, it is okay, but when I try it from Jenkins it is not.

[Here is how I try to build in Jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA1p9.png)

Here is the simple code:

```html
Help
    [Tags]  help
    Capture Screen
    
    Click   input_id
```

[This is the result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jWyI.png)

As you see it could not see my screen. What should I do to let the "Jenkins process" see my screen?

Comment: Is the jenkins node you end up running your test a *windows* machine ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was, that I installed Jenkins as a Windows service. After I installed via the jenkins.war file, it works.